# Docker executes python scripts only when I stopping the container

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

I'm trying to build a Docker image for my python app (a small api on aiohttp with a couple endpoints)

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /home/emil/Projects/elastic_simple_engine

COPY . .

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000/tcp

CMD ["python3", "entry.py"]
```

The last line of the Dockerfile runs a python script which starts `aiohttp.web.Application()`:

```
# entry.py

# ...a few dozens of code lines above...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Initializing...')
    aiohttp.web.run_app(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=5000)
```

After building an image I'm trying to run the container:
`$ docker run -p 5000:5000 myapp`
Docker runs the container silently without any output in shell but I can't reach my app's host: `127.0.0.1:5000` (everything works perfectly when I launch it without docker).
Only when I stop the container it prints in console the lines that should be shown during app's launch and shuts down:

```
Initializing...
======== Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000 ========
(Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Please, help me figure out that I do wrong.

Comment: Add some debugging `print()` lines to your *"...a few dozens of code lines above..."* and see where it gets stuck exactly.

Comment: @Klaus D. Tried. It also prints it on stopping the container.

Comment: Try the command `["python3", "-v", "-u", "entry.py"]`! And post *all* relevant code and output.

Comment: @Klaus D. [after running container](https://github.com/ImHereByChance/simple-full-text-search-service/blob/docker_issue/on_run.txt) and [after stopping it](https://github.com/ImHereByChance/simple-full-text-search-service/blob/docker_issue/on_stop.txt)

Comment: Everything look fine from the output side. Now try to use the IP `0.0.0.0` as host!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR**

Set host to `0.0.0.0`

---

`127.0.0.1` is the IP address to local interface. It can only communicate **within** the same host.

`0.0.0.0` means a server (in this context) would listen to every available network interface (including `127.0.0.1`).

Here, since you are not sharing the docker network, `127.0.0.1` is only available inside the container and not from outside the container. You should use `0.0.0.0` to access it from outside the container or pass `--network="host"` in `docker run` but this can have other complications with port sharing.